# How to register a formatter for a type in ThymeLeaf (non-web environment)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot based application (SpringBoot 3.2.3). The application is not a web application, i.e. it does not use servlets, views etc.

In the application, I want to create a report in the HTML format and send it via email. For creating the HTML, I want to use ThymeLeaf. I do it like this:

```java
Context context = new Context();

context.setVariable("reportName", reportName);
context.setVariable("someOtherData", data);

return templateEngine.process("report", context);
```

Some of the values to be displayed in the report are of type `java.time.Duration`, others are of type `java.util.Date` (and some others). My goal is that those values are automatically formatted as I like it.

For that purpose, I created Printer classes and registered them in the Spring registry:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addPrinter(new DatePrinter());
        registry.addPrinter(new DurationPrinter());
    }

}
```

where e.g. the `DatePrinter` looks like

```java
public class DatePrinter implements Printer<Date> {

    @Override
    public String print(Date date, Locale locale) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
    }

}
```

But that registrations do not seem to have any effect: In the report, all the values are displayed via their `toString` method.

I also tried to register the formatters as `Formatter`s rather than `Printer`s, but it still didn't work.

In my view, I did everything as described e.g. in [the Thymeleaf docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#configuring-a-conversion-service). Could anybody tell me how I can register custom formatters for types?

I've seen some question to this topic here on SO, but they all are for the WebMvc context.

Thank you!

Comment: What does the template look like? Are you using the [double bracket syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#data-conversion-formatting) `${{...}}` to apply data conversion?

Comment: I mostly use the inline notation: `<td>[[${process.startTime}]]</td>`, where the field `startTime` is a `java.util.Date`. My custom formatter does not get applied to it. The same result is with `<td th:text="${{process.startTime}}">...</td>`.

Comment: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/324

Comment: Per the docs, the ONLY time a conversion service is automatically applied to single-brace syntax is when using `th:field` -- https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#double-brace-syntax (under 9.2).  I know it doesn't fix the problem, but you do need to be using `${{process.startTime}}` once you figure out how to set your converters.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! You are absolutely right! When I write the expression as `th:text` I get the exception `org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.Duration] to type [java.lang.String]`. So the program tries to perform the correct conversion but can't find the appropriate converter. Apparently my code with `addFormatter` works on a wrong instance. But how to get the instance used by the templateEngine, I don't know.

With Dates there were not a difference because Spring has a default converter for Dates.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by doing this:

Application Configuration:

```
public static void spring() {
  SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext app = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("quickthymeleaftest.formatter");
  resolver.setApplicationContext(app);
  resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/html/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".html");
  resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
  
  SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
  engine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
  ConversionService c = app.getBean(ConversionService.class);
  
  Context context = new Context();
  final ThymeleafEvaluationContext evaluationContext = new ThymeleafEvaluationContext(app, c);
  context.setVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME, evaluationContext);
  context.setVariable("blah", new Blah());
  
  String html = engine.process("index", context);
  System.out.println(html);
}
```

In the package quickthymeleaftest.formatter:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean(name="conversionService")
    public ConversionService getConversionService() {
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<>();
        converters.add(new BlahConverter());
        bean.setConverters(converters); //add converters
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return bean.getObject();
    }
}
```

And

```
public class BlahConverter implements Converter<Blah, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(Blah blah) {
        return "Blah: " + blah.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint! `ThymeleafEvaluationContext` was the key to the solution! I did it in a bit more simple way. I didn't construct the context myself but rather injected it and the conversion service to my class. Then I added one more variable to the ThLeaf context: `context.setVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME, new ThymeleafEvaluationContext(applicationContext, conversionService));`. All the printers are used now.

Comment: Now there is just one problem left. At one place I wand to generate a link (href). I have a start part of the URL and need to construct the full one: `${basePart}/products/${productId}/details`. This does not work as I'd expect. Do you happen to have an idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: The eventual implementation looks like this:

```java
public class ReportBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private final TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Autowired
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private final ConversionService conversionService;
    
    public String buildReport(String reportNamen, SomeOtherData someOtherData) {
        Context context = new Context();

        context.setVariable("reportName", reportName);
        context.setVariable("someOtherData", data);
        
        context.setVariable(
            ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME,
            new ThymeleafEvaluationContext(applicationContext, conversionService));
        

        return templateEngine.process("report", context);
    }

}
```

Other classes from the original question were not changed.

Many thanks to **@Metroids** for the hint!